# Extract human readable memory usage for Pandas data frame

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame:

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': range(1, 10000)})
```

I can get a nice human-readable thing saying that it has a memory usage of 78.2 KB using `df.info()`:

> ```
> df.info()
> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
> RangeIndex: 9999 entries, 0 to 9998
> Data columns (total 1 columns):
>  #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
> ---  ------  --------------  -----
>  0   A       9999 non-null   int64
> dtypes: int64(1)
> memory usage: 78.2 KB
> ```

I can get an unhelpful statement with similar effect using `df.memory_usage()` (and this is how Pandas itself calculates its own memory usage) but would like to avoid having to roll my own. I've looked at the `df.info` source and traced the source of the string all the way to [this line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4bfe3d07b4858144c219b9346329027024102ab6/pandas/io/formats/info.py#L834).

How is this specific string generated and how can I pull that out so I can print it to a log?

Nb I can't parse the `df.info()` output because it prints directly to buffer; calling `str` on it just returns `None`.

Nb [This line](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/4bfe3d07b4858144c219b9346329027024102ab6/pandas/io/formats/info.py#L462) also does not help, what is initialised is merely a boolean flag for whether memory usage should be printed at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an instance of [`pandas.io.formats.info.DataFrameInfo`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/259a15ce7e9c2f18cc6c1d37f1c670d413cd23bb/pandas/io/formats/info.py#L451) and read the [`memory_usage_string`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/259a15ce7e9c2f18cc6c1d37f1c670d413cd23bb/pandas/io/formats/info.py#L419-L422) property, which is exactly what [`df.info()` does](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/frame.py#L3225-L3228):

```
>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 9999 entries, 0 to 9998
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   A       9999 non-null   int64
dtypes: int64(1)
memory usage: 78.2 KB
```

```
>>> pd.io.formats.info.DataFrameInfo(df).memory_usage_string.strip()
'78.2 KB'
```

If you're passing `memory_usage` to `df.info`, you can pass it directly to `DataFrameInfo`:

```
pd.io.formats.info.DataFrameInfo(df, memory_usage='deep').memory_usage_string.strip()
```

Comment: This is the correct answer; I had figured out that what was being referenced was an on-the-fly-generated inherited property rather than something populated by a constructor just before looking back here. I imported it directly and then wrote `DataFrameInfo(data=chunk, memory_usage='deep').memory_usage_string.strip()`

Comment: Also, re improvement of the answer (supposedly what comments are about). I would link to the [property declaration](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/259a15ce7e9c2f18cc6c1d37f1c670d413cd23bb/pandas/io/formats/info.py#L420).

Comment: @ifly6 Good idea! I actually intended to link to that one, but I messed up and linked to the wrong one.

Comment: The property declaration was in fact what I had wanted to find the whole time, but I had expected that a string would have instead been passed via constructor or otherwise populated by something called there (I usually code in Java).